# Copy records in mysql with relationships in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, copy

i have 3 different tables. They connected with each other with ID column in tables.

```
table "Purchase"
table "Catalog" has 'purchase_id' column in table
table "Product" has 'catalog_id' column in its table.
```

What is the way to copy recrds in one click some already active "Purchase" with all catalogs and product which it ccontains?

Looks like this post [Duplicate a record in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632680/duplicate-a-record-in-mysql) more or less connected. What is the way to do it?

Comment: use SQL `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` and everything is same

Comment: Thx, i will try and do further research.

Answer (score 0):

Do an 'insert select':

```
  insert into <table> ( purchase_id, catalog_id, product_id ) 
     select purchase_id, catalog_id, product_id from Purchase 
       join Catalog using ( purchase_id )
       join Product using ( catalog_id )
   where <some condition>;
```

Comment: Not sure this code will help me. I think that i need in 2 step get mysql_insert_id() for new purchase_id and catalog_id to use it in tables. Because i do not need just copy i want dublicate(clone) with new id.